# How to change keys of a array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the below array:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "73"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "58"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "82"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "84"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "74"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "59"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "72"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "78"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "77"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "71"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

I want the **keys** **indexes** of array to be replaced with position values. The output should be like below:

```
array(10) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "73"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "58"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "82"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "84"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "74"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "59"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "6"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "72"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "78"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "7"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "77"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "71"
    ["position"]=>
    string(1) "8"
  }
}
```

I tried the below code but it just prints one element in array:

```
$newarr = array();

$values = $this->request->get( 'values', null );

foreach ($values as $oldkey => $value) {
    $position = $value["position"];
    $newarr[$position] = $values[$oldkey];
    $values=$newarr;
    unset($newarr);
}
var_dump($values);exit;
```

var_dump result of `$values` is

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 8 in ResourcesController.php</b> 
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 9 in ResourcesController.php</b> on line <b>367</b><br />
array(1) {
  [8]=>
  NULL
}`
```

Comment: You can't do that. You can't have an array with multiple values with the same key.

Comment: You cannot have indexes with the same value. You have multiple positions with the same value - they are not unique, and can therefor not be used as indexes in the array.

Comment: Nice catch Nick! Didn't see that at first glance

Comment: @Nick yes it's a typo.

Comment: So what will happen if two have the same position then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) will be enough to help you with.

```
$result = array_column($yourarray, null, 'position');
```

> **column_key** The column of values to return. This value may be an integer key of
>   the column you wish to retrieve, or it may be a string key name for an
>   associative array or property name. It may also be NULL to return
>   complete arrays or objects (this is useful together with index_key to
>   reindex the array).

**Syntax**

```
array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = NULL ] ) : array
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/209798f996122c7c30068f6b573b6c033606b9e6).

Comment: Your working demo is not working since it has removed two items

Comment: @Andreas It's a **Typo**.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_combine()` along with `range()` and `count()`

```
$array = array_combine(range(1, count($arr)), $arr);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/k0XTj

Reference:

[array_combine()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php)

[range()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

[count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)